# Scam ERC 20 smart Contract

Tags: scam

I was cheated with Apply mining pool rewards
ERC-20 Smart Contract, how can I block money? or how can I recover them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do to get your funds back. Once tokens \ Ethereum has been withdrawn from your account - they are lost.

There is no way of recovering lost tokens.

For future references, please do **not** deploy contracts you've copy/pasted from somewhere, unless you fully understand exactly what the code does.
You can also use ChatGPT, or any AI to help you understand the code (although be careful with that, as there's always a chance the AI is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Well u can't just retrive those funds but there is hope , track the trnxs and see if funds beign routed to centralized exchange , then u may contact with particular exchange .